# SQL Server : setting a default for a query using left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that shows customer waits per category which updates every 5 minutes. Sometimes there might not be any customer waiting in a category. For those categories I want to show the time even if it is null

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2: This holds my category information TABLE NAME TRIAGE_INFORMATION

| standard_triage | category |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Waiting |
| 1 | Category 1 |
| 2 | Category 2 |
| 3 | Category 3 |
| 4 | Category 4 |
| 5 | Category 5 |

My query:

```
SELECT
    CAST(1900 AS INT) AS SITEID, 
    CASE
        WHEN W.WAIT_BLENDED_S = 0 OR W.WAIT_BLENDED_S IS NULL THEN '0 Minutes'
        WHEN W.WAIT_BLENDED_S = 1 THEN '1 Second'    
        WHEN W.WAIT_BLENDED_S < 3600 THEN CAST((W.WAIT_BLENDED_S / 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes'
        WHEN W.WAIT_BLENDED_S < 3600 * 2 THEN CAST((W.WAIT_BLENDED_S / 3600) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' Hour and ' + CAST(((W.WAIT_BLENDED_S / 60) % 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes' 
        WHEN W.WAIT_BLENDED_S >= 3600 * 2 THEN CAST((W.WAIT_BLENDED_S / 3600) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' Hours and ' + CAST(((W.WAIT_BLENDED_S / 60) % 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes'
        ELSE 'ERROR'
    END AS VISUALVALUE,
    W.WAIT_BLENDED_S,
    CONCAT(REPLACE(CONVERT(char(11), W.DATA_TIME, 113), ' ', '/'), ' ',  FORMAT(W.DATA_TIME, 'hh:mm:ss tt')) AS LASTUPDATED,
    DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS BATCHID
FROM 
    TRIAGE_INFORMATION C
LEFT JOIN 
    CALC_BLENDED_TEST W ON W.STANDARD_TRIAGE = C.STANDARD_TRIAGE
ORDER BY 
    C.STANDARD_TRIAGE
```

What I tried:

I replaced with `ISNULL`, and `COALESCE` on `LASTUPDATED`, but it keeps returning empty.

Final required result:

[image]

Comment: And what date do you want to show? Today's date, the date of JFK, 19700101? `Concat(Replace(CONVERT(char(11), ISNULL(W.DATA_TIME, GETDATE()), 113), ' ','/'),' ',  FORMAT(ISNULL(W.DATA_TIME, GETDATE()),'hh:mm:ss tt'))` should probably display something, not sure what issues were you having with the ISNULL/COALESCE

Comment: what date do you want it to show when there is no data in CALC_BLENDED_TEST?

Comment: I want to show the same date as the ones that are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to CROSS JOIN all triages against your base table, and then aggregate things:

```sql
SELECT  CONCAT(Replace(CONVERT(char(11), ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory = Standard_triage THEN TimeENTRY END), MAX(TimeENTRY)), 113), ' ','/'),' '
    ,  FORMAT(ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory = Standard_triage THEN CAST(TimeENTRY AS DATETIME2) END), MAX(CAST(TimeENTRY AS DATETIME2))),'hh:mm:ss tt')) AS LASTUPDATED
,   standard_triage
,   ISNULL(MAX(v.visual), '0 Minutes') AS VISUALVALUE
,   MAX(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory = Standard_triage THEN WAITINGINSECONDS END) AS WAIT_BLENDED_S
,   DATEDIFF(SECOND, '19700101', SYSUTCDATETIME()) AS BATCHID
FROM    (
    VALUES  (2773, 0, '2023-11-21 16:30:13.0330000')
    ,   (5773, 3, '2023-11-21 16:30:13.0330000')
    ,   (7152, 5, '2023-11-21 16:30:13.0330000')
) t ([WAITINGINSECONDS], [CUSTOMERCATEGORY], [TIMEENTRY])
CROSS JOIN (
    VALUES  (0, N'Waiting')
    ,   (1, N'Category 1')
    ,   (2, N'Category 2')
    ,   (3, N'Category 3')
    ,   (4, N'Category 4')
    ,   (5, N'Category 5')
) t2 (standard_triage,category)
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  CASE WHEN CustomerCategory = Standard_triage THEN 
        CASE
                WHEN WAITINGINSECONDS = 0 OR WAITINGINSECONDS IS NULL THEN '0 Minutes'
                WHEN WAITINGINSECONDS = 1 THEN  '1 Second'    
                WHEN WAITINGINSECONDS < 3600 THEN CAST((WAITINGINSECONDS / 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes'
                WHEN WAITINGINSECONDS < 3600 * 2 THEN CAST((WAITINGINSECONDS / 3600) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' Hour and ' + CAST(((WAITINGINSECONDS / 60) % 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes' 
                WHEN WAITINGINSECONDS >= 3600 * 2 THEN CAST((WAITINGINSECONDS / 3600) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' Hours and ' + CAST(((WAITINGINSECONDS / 60) % 60) AS nvarchar(10)) + ' minutes'
                ELSE 'ERROR'
        END END AS visual
       ) v
GROUP BY standard_triage
```

The trick is that every field must do something like:
`MAX(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory = Standard_triage THEN WAITINGINSECONDS END)` thus making sure only matching values are getting the real value.

To fill out the NULLs, one wraps it in an ISNULL `ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN CustomerCategory = Standard_triage THEN WAITINGINSECONDS END), MAX(WAITINGINSECONDS))`.
This gets pretty chatty after a while though.

Outputs:

| LASTUPDATED | standard_triage | VISUALVALUE | WAIT_BLENDED_S | BATCHID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-11-21/ 04:30:13 PM | 0 | 46 minutes | 2773 | 1700655478 |
| 2023-11-21/ 04:30:13 PM | 1 | 0 Minutes | NULL | 1700655478 |
| 2023-11-21/ 04:30:13 PM | 2 | 0 Minutes | NULL | 1700655478 |
| 2023-11-21/ 04:30:13 PM | 3 | 1 Hour and 36 minutes | 5773 | 1700655478 |
| 2023-11-21/ 04:30:13 PM | 4 | 0 Minutes | NULL | 1700655478 |
| 2023-11-21/ 04:30:13 PM | 5 | 1 Hour and 59 minutes | 7152 | 1700655478 |